# Entity Framework: Using DynamicLinq in a generic filter method

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, generics, dynamic-linq

I am working on a mostly generic application with one Filter method:

```
IQueryable<T> Filter<T>(IQueryable<T> query, Filter filter) where T : IDataBaseEntity
```

Here is the filter object being passed in:

```
{
    Field: "Header.Title",
    Operator: "contains",
    Value: "asdf"
}
```

I have a switch for the operator (contains, <, >, ==, etc) to handle each one differently, but I will just focus on "contains" for this example.

The "query" variable being passed in is a generic list of interfaces, an interface that all 200 of my entities inherit from. I do not even have access to the entity types from this namespace.

In this example, the "query" parameter is an IQueryable of entity "Page". A typical example of DynamicLinq for Contains would be the following:

```
Expression<Func<Page, bool>> exp = l => l.Contains(filter.Value);
query = query.Where("@0(it)", exp);
```

However, this part of my application is not strongly typed, my domain doesn't know what a "Page" is, and instead it's using the inherited IDataBaseEntity as the Func<> first type. I get an exception because "No property or field 'Header' exists in type 'IDataBaseEntity'". I tried a variety of other options but ended up with this being the primary issue.

NOTE: I need to keep this an IQueryable and do NOT want to turn it into an IEnumerable at any point for performance reasons. The query is intended to only be run (.AsEnumerable()) after filtering, sorting and paging.

Is it possible to run dynamic linq against IQueryable with an interface type in a namespace that knows nothing about my actual entity types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about not using the interface at all - Dynamic Linq is late bound anyway. You can apply the dynamic `Where` on `IQueryable<T>` and the result will be `IQueryable<T>`.

As soon as you can build the string predicate correctly, the following should work:

```
query = query.Where("Header.Title.Contains(@0)", filter.Value);
```

Comment: Ah thanks. This looks to be 90% the correct answer so I'll mark it as correct. A few notes for anyone else reading this post: instead of nothing or "T : IDataBaseEntity", the method type needs to be "T : class", otherwise if you have a strongly typed query and attempt to end with .OfType<T>() to pass compilation, you'll get an EF complex/primitive exception at runtime. 
I also ended up using LinqKit's query.AsExpandable() to avoid "The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to Entities". Not sure if there's performance hit of AsExpandable or if there's another way around.